# How to use write() Method on a many2many field?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

~...py

```
@api.onchange('test_record')
def abcde(self):
    rec = self.test_record.id
    res = self.env['anc'].browse(rec)
    res.write({'partner_id': (4,self.partner_id.id)})
```

On the above code what im trying to do is updating a partner in the browsed model(res),But the field named partner_id is a many2many field,where we can select multiple partners.

Comment: Use a special [commands](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L3436) format to manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the field. This format is a ***list*** of triplets. Check this [note](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/api.py#L164) if you are trying to update it from onchange method.

Comment: My onchange triggering field is not one2many or many2many field,It is a many2one field,After selecting the many2one field it triggers the onchange method and i need to update the many2many field after that.

Comment: Why do you need to use browse for `anc` record? Please add the definition of the Many2many field and the `test_record` related model.

Comment: partner_id = fields.Many2many('res.partner', string="Specialist")

Comment: that many2many field is in the model anc, So selecting the field named test_record,needs to trigger the onchange method and write on the field partner_id in the model anc

Comment: what im trying to do is on selecting the field test_record(Many2one)in model A, triggers a onchange function and update the partner id(Many2many) in the model 'anc'.

Comment: When i tried to do the same code in the field(Many2one) it was working,but i need to make the field many2many since i needs to tag more than one partner in the field 'partner_id'

Comment: Try to write to the Many2many field like shown in my first comment, `res.write({'partner_id': [(4,self.partner_id.id)]})`

Comment: yea its working now, ive used ' ( ) ' instead of ' [ ] ' as u mentioned in the last comment.thanks kenly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220600/discussion-between-raihan-and-kenly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please note this is only for `many2many` or `one2many` as following:

```
(0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
(1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
(2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
(3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
(4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
(5,)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records). Needs to be a tuple, thus the comma.
(6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
```

but in your case it is probably `many2one` which should be as

```py
def abcde(self):
    rec = self.test_record.id
    res = self.env['anc'].browse(rec)
    res.write({'partner_id':[(4,self.partner_id.id)]}) # you need to add it as list
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,But the field in the write method is not many2one it is many2many in my case.