# how to add elements to an existing Many2One fieldusing inheritance in Odoo 14?

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo, odoo-14

I have a custom module and i am trying to modify "Time off module" by inheriting it ! and I want to add an item in the existing Many2One (dropdown) field. what would be the syntax to do that? for both python and XML. The model name is "hr.leave" and the field is "holiday_status_id", I want to add one more element in the dropdown as "CL" or "Casual leave".

Comment: Please add the related model and the field domain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625699/7045119

Comment: @Kenly hello sir, sorry for the incomplete information. i added the model name and field.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `hr.leave.type` record and make sure it is not hidden when applying the [domain](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/hr_holidays/data/hr_holidays_data.xml#L18).

You can use a data file, I modified the `Sick Time Off` to add a new leave type:

```
<record id="holiday_new_type" model="hr.leave.type">
    <field name="name">New type</field>
    <field name="allocation_type">no</field>
    <field name="color_name">red</field>
    <field name="validity_start" eval="time.strftime('%Y-01-01')"/>
    <field name="leave_notif_subtype_id" ref="hr_holidays.mt_leave_sick"/>
    <field name="responsible_id" ref="base.user_admin"/>
</record>
```

You can check the [hr_holidays](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/hr_holidays/data/hr_holidays_data.xml#L18) data file for more examples.

Comment: Hello sir, thankyou so mych :) it worked, can you explain what are these fields "allocation_type", "color_name" , "vaidity_start" and "leave_notif_subtype_id" :) and how did you find out the external ID "hr_holidays.mt_leave_sick" ?

Comment: You already have an explanation in the declaration of those fields, you can check it at [hr_leave_type](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/hr_holidays/models/hr_leave_type.py#L20). I added the module name to the record id because I referenced the record outside the `hr_holidays` module. Check [External identifier](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/glossary.html#term-external-identifier) for more details.